# How do you play sound in Python WITHOUT downloading anything

Tags: python, audio

I have been looking for ages on ways to find out how to make idle python play sound such as wav.

The solutions I have found are used by programs such as pygame. I can't download pygame or any other program.

Many thanks

Comment: What version of python are you using. Python 3, has a wav library. https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play a sound without downloading anything, you use the code:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('FILENAMEHERE.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

keep everything the same apart from FILENAMEHERE

Answer (score 0):

Why are you unable to download anything? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/playsound/1.2.1 - link for playsound module it is very easy to download. You can download it using pip by navigating with cmd to your python folder (usualy C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32) and writing: python -m pip install playsound (if you are using python 3). I think that is the easiest and the fastest way for you to play sound if you have any other questions about this let me know.

p.s
If you need to you can download pip here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
Hope I was helpful. :)

Comment: I cant download anything as its coursework and its intended to be used by anyone